# Add comments to atributtes of Postgresql from Java

Tags: java, postgresql

I want to know if there is a way of writing comments to attributes on Postrgresql from Java 8. I am using hibernate to generate the tables, if it could generate the comments for the atributes on Postgres would be nice. I searched for an annotation to do that but I have not found.

Comment: You can run a SQL statement to define a comment on a column: `comment on column foo.id is 'The ID'`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah, but they want to do it with Hibernate DDL generation. Which, like most of Hibernate, is pretty limited as soon as you step outside lowest-common-denominator features.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I tend to translate ORM with "obfuscated relational model"... Comments on columns/tables are nothing special to Postgres. Nearly all DBMS support them - surprisingly enough the syntax is the same (except for SQL Server) even though this has never been specified by the SQL standard.